# Singularity of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function in an open set around some $c \in \mathbb C$, but excluding $c$. Moreover, assume that the Laurent series for $f$ around $c$ converges.

Is it then true that if for $\vert x \vert>\vert c \vert$ we know that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow c, \vert x \vert >\vert c \vert}f(x)(x-c)=a \text{ exists}$$
that $f$ has at most a finite order pole at $c$?

Comment: Are you allowing $a=\infty?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these conditions do not imply that the singularity at $c$ is at worst a pole. Consider
$$f(x) = \exp\biggl(\frac{1}{1-x}\biggr).$$
This has an essential singularity at $1$, but $f$ is bounded on the set $\{x \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert x\rvert > 1\}$ since the Möbius transform $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1-x}$ maps this region to $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Re} z < 1/2\}$, so
$$\lim_{\substack{x \to 1 \\ \lvert x\rvert > 1}} f(x)(x-1) = 0.$$

Comment: well, is your function holomorphic arounnd $1$ and has a convergent Laurent series expansion?

Comment: Yes, it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$ and its Laurent expansion consequently converges on all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$. (Due to the nature of $f$, this can also be seen without any theory about Laurent expansions. It's $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(x-1)^{-n}\,,$$ and the convergence directly follows from the global convergence of the exponential series.)

Comment: thank you.......